# Why is STDIN_FILENO always zero?

Tags: c, file-descriptor, stdio, tty

I wanted to know if there was a simple but logical reason for having set the `STDIN_FILENO` as `0` in the stdio header, I realized about this when I was testing a more complex code, here's the short version of it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void main(char **argv)
{
    char *promt = "Not a terminal";
    int inter = 1;
    int counter = 1;
    isatty(STDIN_FILENO) == 0 ? inter = 0 : inter;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        inter == 1 ? write(1, promt, 16) : inter; 
        fflush(stdout);
        counter++;
        
    }

}
```

Also, if possible to know, what's the relation between `STDIN_FILENO` and `Stream`?

Comment: I don't understand either of your questions, and you shouldn't be asking more than one at a time anyway

Comment: [Because the standard says so.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) I don't understand your question about `Stream`, this is the first and only appearance of that word in your question and it's not clear to me what it is referencing.

Comment: How did you come up with `void main(char **argv)`? I have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: The argument for `isatty` is a file descriptor. That can be a stream from redirected file or terminal. Terminal is kind of special so it can have its own fixed number.

Comment: It is chosen to be zero. It is standard. No logic required.

Comment: Why is the first letter of the alphabet always `A`? Why isn't it sometimes `B` or `Z`?

Comment: Interesting way of setting `inter` to zero, by the way... I like, too, `inter &= isatty(...);` or for other values than 1 `inter &= -isatty(...);` (note the minus sign) :b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `STDIN_FILENO` is **defined** as zero [per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html):

> The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the
> ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements described here
> and the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of POSIX.1-2017
> defers to the ISO C standard. [Option End]
>
> A file with associated buffering is called a stream and is declared to
> be a pointer to a defined type FILE. The fopen() function shall create
> certain descriptive data for a stream and return a pointer to
> designate the stream in all further transactions. Normally, there are
> three open streams with constant pointers declared in the <stdio.h>
> header and associated with the standard open files.
>
> At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be
> opened explicitly: standard input (for reading conventional input),
> standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error
> (for writing diagnostic output). When opened, the standard error
> stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output
> streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined
> not to refer to an interactive device.
>
> The following symbolic values in `<unistd.h>` define the file
> descriptors that shall be associated with the C-language `stdin`,
> `stdout`, and `stderr` when the application is started:
>
> `STDIN_FILENO`
>
> Standard input value, `stdin`. **Its value is 0**.

Answer (score 4):

`STDIN_FILENO` is POSIX and is required to be `0`.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html

Comment: That doesn't explain why.

Comment: Stdin stdout and stderr are 0 1 and 2 as file descriptors on posix systems.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. Local gravity points close to the center of the Earth. But why? My point is the question is unanswerable within the limited scope of SO. You're better off closing it than posting an answer like this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist POSIX defines `STDIN_FILENO` as "always 0".  Why is that not good enough?

Comment: @MadPhysicist if you want to go the "but why" route no answer is answerable ever. Why is stdin 0? Because it's defined as such? But why? Because that's how the posix standard defines it. But why? Because that's how people define it. But why? Because they thought it is convenient to have the most useful file descriptors starting at 0, 1, 2. But why? Because  they were able to make such a reasonable decision. But why? Because they are intelligent ppl with experience in programming. But why? Because they were passionate about programming. But why?

Comment: I have a why : maybe they just wrote `enum {STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO};`. Here's your why.

Comment: @Scouarn. Well, following bolov: But *why* did they do so? :b